# Aish Kodesh - Edition Recommendations

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, chasidut-hasidism, holocaust-shoah

Can someone recommend a good edition of Aish Kodesh by R. Kalonymus Kalman Shapiro? I am looking for an English or Hebrew edition.

Comment: Isn't there only one English and one Hebrew edition? What are the options you're asking from.

Comment: As a *limud zchut*, the OP might be interested in French. I mention it here because one of the other similar books extracted from the Shoah, a set of responsa on Shoah-related topics called "Mi-maamakim" written by R Oshry, was translated to French and remains available in that language despite not being available in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate versions, 1 for the Hebrew version, 1 for the English version.

[**Hebrew version: Sefer Aish Kodesh**](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/sefer-aish-kodesh/29760)

> Torah Discourses on the weekly Torah portions from the Years of Wrath, by Rabbi Klonimus Kalmish of Piasetzna(1889-1943), during his days at the Warsaw Getto (1940-1943), spoken on shabbats and holidays. His writings were found in the ruins of the Warsaw Getto.

And the [Feldheim version](https://www.feldheim.com/aish-kodesh-hebrew-only-1-1)

[**English version: Warmed By The Fire Of The Aish Kodesh**](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/warmed-by-the-fire-of-the-aish-kodesh/2529)

> [...] Because of this influence, Rav Moshe Weinberger chose to name a newly established shul in Woodmere, New York, after the Rebbe's sefer Aish Kodesh and instituted an annual hilula on the Rebbe's yahrtzeit, attended by approximately 1,000 Jews of all types and ages from throughout the tri-state area. This sefer consists of the Torah taught by Rav Weinberger at these annual hilula gatherings.

So basically, the last one from Eichlers contains the teachings of Rav Weinberger on Sefer Aish Kodesh.

The English version is also available on other sites, such as [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1680250221)

Comment: Thanks for this information. It looks like the Hebrew version from Eichler's and the one from Feldheim are actually both the Feldheim addition. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: That's correct! The publisher is Feldheim Publishers, just a different retailer.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: @Bs234570 I only mention this because you are still new on the site. The green mark is meant to signify this is in your view the best answer. Normally it is best to wait for a few days until you see all answers, because it is hard to know the best answer when you have only seen one. One case in which granting the mark right away makes sense  is when you are looking for something and the answer tells you where to find it. But for more open questions, I suggest to come back to the question a few days later. Please don't read this as fishing for points, I'm just sharing thoughts

Comment: @Bs234570 and if you are interested see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide I wrote to fully understanding the site. It is good to have new thoughtful and knowledgeable members like you !

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 English books extracted or translated from the writings of the Aish Kodesh, R Kalonymos Kalman Shapira Hyd.

- [Sacred Fire: Torah from the Years of Fury 1939-1942](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/076576217X) which are commentaries on the weekly *parsha* and on each major holidays. This is the closest to a full translation of the original sefer
- [The holy fire: the teachings of R Kalonymus Kalman Shapira](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0765760266) which a reviewer called "a manual on comprehending evil from within God"
- [To Heal the Soul: The Spiritual Journal of a Chasidic Rebbe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568213069) which is the translation of a journal he left behind

All 3 are excellent if you are interested in understanding the Aish Kodesh, but they are not easy reading. They convey a deep sense of anguish and suffering, increasing as time passes, as he tries to make sense of the pain they are going through.